# 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' when adding UITableView to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to create a PageViewController with multiple horizontally-paging UITableViews inside. The UITableViews are stored in an array; I use the UIPageViewController `setViewControllers` method to add the very first object in the array to the PageVC:

```
 [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:[self.tableViews objectAtIndex:0] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then I add the remaining UITableViews to the PageViewController by using the `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods.

However the `setViewControllers` method is producing the following error:

```
 -[UITableView count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c347e00
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c347e00'
```

Why is this error happening?

Comment: show the codes you use to create tableViews array, make sure all of them is properly created and have dataSource set up

Comment: It looks a bit strange that you use `tableview` as `viewcontroller` inside your `pageViewController`

Comment: @user2181948 Is it working in the viewControllers parameter? Because you used  `UITableView` instead of `UIViewController` as a parameter.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Now I'm getting the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`, which is an entirely different error..

Comment: You should use `viewController` as a parameter! have a look at my answer and the Apple API doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the method first you are using [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers?language=objc):

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)viewControllers 
                 direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated 
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

It says the parameters should be the viewControllers

> **Parameters:**
>
> viewControllers The view controller or view controllers to be
>   displayed.

So, you have to take a `UIViewcontroller` or `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

You need to pass view controllers and not views to the page view controller. For each UITableView, you need a UITableViewController.

If you change your variable `self.tableViews` to `self.tableViewControllers` (with the UITableViewController you create for each UITableView) you're half way there.

The other problem is that the first parameter for `setViewControllers` should be an NSArray. (NSArray has a selector called `count`.)

Change your code to wrap the first table view in an array when you're adding it:

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[ [self.tableViewControllers objectAtIndex:0] ] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil]
```

Comment: `setViewControllers` cannot be an `NSObject`.`UITableView` is a child class of `NSObject`. `UIViewController` should be passed here in the parameter.

Comment: I missed that the original question had `UITableView`s and not `UITableViewController`s. I've fixed that.

Comment: OP has already mentioned that it is `UITableView`s. My point is before posting the answer you should check it by yourself 2, 3 times.